# Is there a way to encode a URL in velocity template

Tags: apache, velocity

Excuse my ignorance but I am new to Velocity and trying to fix someone else's problem.  I need to encode a URL inside the velocity template.  I create a url and as part of the query string I pass in a page name a user created.  This page can contain special characters like ëðû.  The url would look like [http://foo.com/page1/jz?page=SpecialChars_ëðû](http://foo.com/page1/jz?page=SpecialChars_%C3%AB%C3%B0%C3%BB)

Answer (score 4):

To encode URL inside a template you can use:

`$esc.url($myUrl)`

which is a part of [EscapeTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html).

Note:
This required to use [velocity tools jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity-tools/2.0), in addition to the velocity jar.
(It will not throw exception if you will not have it).
Moreover, you might want to check you configuration, as describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989472/spring-mvc-velocity-template-structure)

Comment: Is there anything you need to do to enable the escape tools? I tried added this to my template, like $esc.url($myParam) but it was treated as a literal.

Comment: Do you have any tools enabled at all? How to enable them depends on how you initialize your velocity engine.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is late. Here is how I solved this today. In the class calling the engine, you could say

```
configure("esc",new EscapeTool());
context.put("url", "http://www.google.com");
```

Now in the template you could say

> $esc.url($url)

Answer (score -1):

I was just not willing to use the EscapeTool in velocity for an url-encoding.
Hence, here's the solution i got -

you can use **$httpUtil.decodeURL($siteURL)** / **$httpUtil.encodeURL($siteURL)** for URL Encoding in Velocity

Also ,you can use `$htmlUtil.escapeAttribute()` for escaping text/html Content in Velocity.

`$htmlUtil.escapeAttribute($refSiteName)`