# Spring MVC & Velocity : Template structure

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

I'd like to achieve this kind of template functionality:

- Have a template defining header, footer, and common parts of complete (x)html webpage
- When returning String from `@Controller` it will define the view included to specific part of template

Like this:

**@Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    return "home_view";
}
```

**views/home_view.vm**

```
<h2>Content title</h2>
<p>Content text</p>
```

**views/template.vm**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Header of page -->
        #include({context variable which contains "home_view"} + ".vm");
        <!-- Footer of page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

*If anybody knows CakePHP, this is similar to its template system*

How can I do this?

Comment: Could be a place to use aspects. Target all controllers with a `@RequestMapping` annotation, and wrap the method with something that returns `template.vm` and puts `home_view.vm` in the `Model`, where `template.vm` can pluck it out and perform the include. Else maybe you could override the DispatcherServlet - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#resolveViewName%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map,%20java.util.Locale,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29

Comment: @PaulGrime but that would mean that every single page would have to have single controller instance, isn't it? But I like that overriding.

Comment: If you want to return something other than `template.vm`, then yes.

Comment: @PaulGrime nope, template should be same for whole site. If you want, write your comments as an answer, so I can accidentally accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final solution based on **@Nathan Bubna** suggestion.

Project is based on **Spring MVC** template, with **Maven** controlled resources.
**Spring version 3.1.1.RELEASE**

*/WEB-INF/web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

*/WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <resources location="/resources/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico"/>
    <resources location="/resources/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.png"/>

    <beans:bean id="velocityConfig"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. 
        If you need different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the 
        resource bundle resolver. -->
    <beans:bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="cache" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="" />
        <beans:property name="layoutUrl" value="layout.vm"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.subpackage" />

</beans:beans>
```

**important pom.xml lines**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: And how do you do the include? How to get the view name requested on the layout page?? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think Spring has support for a VelocityLayoutView. Or, i thought they did.

Comment: I'd be interested in why is this question downvoted. I'm now trying to implement this solution.

Comment: You obviously cannot ;-) I've tried to call the one who did it ;-)